# algebraic integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $d$ is square-free. What is the set of algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q} \left(\sqrt{d} \right) = \{a + b \sqrt{d}:a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$?

The algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ are the complex numbers that are solutions to a polynomial of the form $x^2+a_1x+a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ (i.e. $x$ is an algebraic integer $\Longleftrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is finitely generated as an abelian group). $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q} \left(\sqrt{d} \right)$ since $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}.$

The set of algebraic integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ has two cases, when $d$ is odd and when $d$ is even. For an odd $d$ we obtain the ring $\mathbb{Z} [ \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2}]$ and for the even $d$ we obtain $\mathbb{Z} [\frac{\sqrt{d}}{2}] = \{a + b \frac{\sqrt{d}}{2}:a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$ Not sure where to go, any help welcomed.

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve? It looks like you have the answer to your question (but the answer you have for even $d$ is not correct; it should be $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$).

Comment: Your two cases are wrong: for a *squarefree* integer $d$, the ring of integers in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ is $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ if $d\equiv 2,3\mod 4$ and is $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}]$ when $d\equiv2\mod 4$.

Comment: Don't use $x$ for a number - writing $\mathbb Z[x]$ in that case is very confusing.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Do you mean for the last case to be when $d$ is 1 mod 4?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes I did.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $a+b\sqrt{d}$ is a root of the polynomial $(X-a)^2-db^2$.  If $x$ is an algebraic integer then the coefficients of this polynomial must be integers.

Note that the assumption that $d$ be squarefree is essential here - for example,  $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{18})$, but that the ring of integers of this field is $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$, not $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{18}]$.